# performance remote el-select option 3000 items slow and crush?

Tags: meteor, vue.js, element-ui

Hello this is my first time. I have problem with like that I have 3000 items and I use framework like **vue, element-ui and meteor**. I pull all the items through a remote **el-select** that selects to add more remote select array object.I don't know why it slow performance and crush.

[This is my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNeKh.png)

> // Find item opts method

```
_getItemOpts(query, type) {
  type = type || 'remote'
  let exp = new RegExp(query)
  let selector = {}
  if (exp) {
    selector = {
      itemType: { $ne: 'Bundle' },
      // , 'Sale'
      activityType: { $in: ['Purchase'] },
      status: 'Active',
      $or: [
        { name: { $regex: exp, $options: 'i' } },
        { refNo: { $regex: exp, $options: 'i' } },
        { barcode: { $regex: exp, $options: 'i' } },
      ],
    }
  }

  // Find item
  findItems
    .callPromise({ selector: selector })
    .then(result => {
      // console.log(result)
      if (type == 'remote') {
        this.itemOpts = result          
      
      }
      this.loading = false
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.loading = false
      Notify.error({ message: err })
    })
},
```

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide more information about the error(s) you are getting, and the code provided, is that server side or client side?

Comment: Because of much more code so i can not send all code what exactly like description above and you can see link to picture

Comment: I am happy to help you, but I don't have enough information to go on yet. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for an explanation. If you want to share your meteor project (and database) with me that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Well no magick is here. U tryin to add to DOM 3000 of elements, so no wonder its crashes. Try to narrow results, for example show them only when user enters 3 letters

Comment: look in http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select#remote-search code here . in method u see this if (query !== '') , so try with if (query.length >= 3) for example